# Status bar color: preferredStatusBarStyle doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

Solution I found in stackoverflow - it is override `preferredStatusBarStyle` in view controller but it does not work for me and I cant understand why. Status bar still black.

My prerequisites:
[image: Storyboars]
[image: Status bar]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: ContainerView!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Make Sure These Settings

1. Project->Target->Deployment Info [image: Project->Target->Developement Info]
2. In info.plist [image: in info.plist]

Comment: thank you.However is it possible to make it programmatically?

Comment: you can perform first step by code, but you should add Key in info.plist

Answer (score 2):

Double check   in `info.plist` you are adding flag `View controller-based` status bar appearance to `NO`?

In `Viewcontroller.swift`

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
}
```

Comment: If I could to choose two right answers I choose both. Thank you guys!